# retrieving the image from camera-roll or saved images in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How can i retrieve the specific images which are saved into the camera-roll or saved images in windows phone 8..

does it work in windows phone 8 when we are dealing with sdcard for retrieving.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

1. You can get the user to choose an image from the native picker using the [`PhotoChooserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). ([Example usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))
2. You can query the [`Pictures` property of the `MediaLbrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx) to get direct access to the images. ([Example usage](http://andy-teamg.blogspot.com/2010/07/windows-phone-7-selecting-device-photos.html))

Both methods will include access to images stored  on the SD card.

Comment: Hai matt Lacey

i am new to windows phone 8 development.So can u please give me any example for that.